# Quais os padrões de formatação SQL? Tem alguma ferramenta que faça isso?

Tags: sql, formatação

Fiz uma pergunta parecida, mas sobre javascript. Mas lido muito com códigos SQL e MySQL. Existe algum padrão comumente aceito? Alguém conhece alguma ferramenta que valide ou modifique o código?

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma ferramente online que uso para formatar SQL que esteja muito confuso:

http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Esta ferramenta permite formatar SQL's de vários SGDB's, de forma que fiquem mais "bonitinhos".

Falando em padrão, não acho que exista um, desde que funcione e que seja legível. A formatação pode variar dependendo do caso, e do que se considera *ser legível*. Em muitos casos a formatação de um SQL dá foco em algumas partes, mas deixa outras partes mais compactas... legibilidade é um fator humano, então isso justifica a minha opinião de não haver um padrão.

Comment: Procurei várias vezes e não tinha achado. Muito bom. Tks